# IBM Lenovo A55 Full Driver

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, thinkcentre

I can't find IBM Lenovo Thinkcentre A55 drivers.

http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/MIGR-66440.html this link doesn't work.

Can anybody help find a full driver set for IBM Lenovo Thinkcentre A55?

OS: `Windows XP`.

Comment: The link opens just fine for me. Can you specify how exactly it "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ThinkVantage System Update software to get the latest drivers quick and easy

http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/tvsu-update.html